# .jar file won't run? (I feel like I'm missing something obvious, looked to solutions myself before coming here.)

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I wanted to find out how to create an executable .jar file, so I wrote a small sample program to test it. This sample program takes some default text and turns it into some code based on the Caesar code. Anyway, it outputs normally when run in Eclipse.

I doubt this helps, but here's the source code for the two java classes.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    Caesar caesarCode = new Caesar();
    caesarCode.setDecodedText("this");
    caesarCode.setShiftPos(3);

    String cipherText = caesarCode.deencode(caesarCode.getDecodedText(), caesarCode.getShiftPos());
    System.out.print(cipherText+"\n");

    String plainText = caesarCode.deencode(cipherText, caesarCode.getShiftPos()*-1);
    System.out.print(plainText);
    }
}
```

**Caesar.java**

```
public class Caesar {
// global variables
String encodedText; //  encoded text
String decodedText; //  decoded text
int shiftPos;       //  shift positions to decode message

// getters and setters
public String getEncodedText() {
    return encodedText;
}

public void setEncodedText(String encodedText) {
    this.encodedText = encodedText;
}

public String getDecodedText() {
    return decodedText;
}

public void setDecodedText(String decodedText) {
    this.decodedText = decodedText;
}

public int getShiftPos() {
    return shiftPos;
}

public void setShiftPos(int shiftPos) {
    this.shiftPos = shiftPos;
}

public String deencode (String plainTextArg, int shiftPosArg) {
    // variables
    String plainText = plainTextArg;
    char[] cipherTextArray;
    String cipherText;
    int plainTextSize;
    int shiftPos = shiftPosArg;

    // initialize variables
    char[] plainTextArray = plainText.toCharArray();
    plainTextSize = plainTextArray.length;
    cipherTextArray = new char[plainTextSize];

    // shift cipher String by shiftPos
    for (int i = 0; i < plainTextSize; i++){
        cipherTextArray[i] = (char) (plainTextArray[i] + shiftPos);
    }

    cipherText = String.valueOf(cipherTextArray);

    // return cipher text
    return cipherText;
}
}
```

I created my .jar file this way (on a Mac):

1. Created two directories on Desktop: "classes" and "source"
2. Copied my two files (Caesar.java, Main.java) into the source folder.
3. I compiled the files into .class files in the classes directory with the command "javac -d ../classes *.java"
4. I created a manifest.txt file with the line "Main-Class: Main", and saved it as "manifest.txt" in the classes directory.
5. I then created the .jar file with this command "jar -cvmf manifest.txt main.jar *.class".

The main.jar file was created successfully.

The problem is, when I ran it, nothing happened - no warnings, no popups, no error messages.

I'm thinking that it has something to do with the fact that it outputs to the terminal, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've also looked at many threads on this forum and others, but can't seem to see the problem. I'm going to experiment to see if it works for a GUI application in the meanwhile.

Greatly appreciate your help on this, thanks!

Comment: You gave all the info except how exactly you *ran* it.

Comment: Just to be sure: can you also post the contents of your jar file (`jar tvf main.jar`)?

Comment: Use a proper build tool.

Comment: The page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) indicates the JAR create command is `jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class`, which is slightly different from what you did. Also, it notes about the Manifest file: `Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers either way round works - if the switches are `fm` then it's JAR name first and manifest second, if the switches say `mf` then it's vice versa.

Comment: I thought the file you create was MANIFEST.MF, not manifest.txt.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @CodeChimp the argument to the `m` option can be anything, the jar tool will ensure that the manifest is called `MANIFEST.MF` inside the finished jar file.

Comment: @Disco3 Whoops! I just double clicked the jar file. :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Double click. :)

Comment: @bmargulies What's a proper build tool?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I don't think omitting the -v attribute helped...and I did add a carriage return, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @CodeChimp No that's not a typo - manifest.mf should be the output file, manifest.txt the input. Everything seemed to work fine except for the jar file which refuses to execute!

Comment: If you're going to be doing anything much more complex than this example then it's worth investing the time in installing and learning to use an IDE such as Eclipse, and/or a build tool such as Maven or Ant, rather than stringing together javac, jar and java commands by hand.  It seems like effort to start with but it will pay dividends in the medium to long term.

Comment: @IanRoberts I think I'll look into that. I already use Eclipse, but I don't know how to do it. :( But I think it's useful to know how to do this via the command line. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm thinking that it has something to do with the fact that it outputs to the terminal

If you want to see console output from your program then you will have to run it in the Terminal with `java -jar main.jar`.  If you double click the JAR in the Finder or use the `open` command then it will run but any output will go to the system console log rather than being displayed directly.  You can show system console messages by running `syslog -C`.

Comment: Works! I think a GUI application works fine. I'm currently creating a jar file for a GUI program, will update thread later. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will either need a GUI for your app or you can write your own log output somewhere.  System.out.println() will typically go to the Terminal, but since you are not running in one, then it's up to the OS to decide how to handle it.

Comment: Yup! Works for GUI applications! Rule: GUI = double click jar file. Any program that outputs to the terminal, you'll need java -jar ProgramNameThatContainsMainMethod.jar.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create executable jars from within eclipse if you want to. 
Right click on your project -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR file.

Note that You might need to run your jar file from the command line using `java -jar <jarFile>` to see `System.out.println()` and error messages.

Comment: Yup! Works now! Thanks :) BjornArnelid :D

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to invoke "Run..." dialog. Type `cmd` there and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The Command Prompt window will appear (it's black).

At the prompt type `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\classes` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then type command as suggested above: `java -jar main.jar`

Comment: **Please** pay attention when approving suggested edits 'improving' formatting. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4385056) introduced a syntax error and should have been rejected (the `/` operator was deleted).

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is about that Python question? Uh, ok.